# Transit to Monroe NJ on weekends

Tags: public-transport, new-york-city, new-jersey

This is my first question on this site, sorry if it isn't appropriate.

I'm trying to find the best way to get from Brooklyn, NY to Monroe, NJ, or at least as close as possible, by public transit, on weekends. Monroe is big, but I don't want to give addresses for obvious reasons. It's near exit 8A on the turnpike.

The best I could seem to find was New Brunswick station, which is 26 minutes away by car. I'm having a hard time believing that that is the best one can do, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Have you checked the NJT bus routes?

Comment: @phoog Since I asked this I found an NJT bus stop 18 minutes away in Old Bridge. Still not great but better than the train station at least. Google used to include taxis as part of a public transit trip, but now instead it has you waiting for the bus to come on Monday if you search on Friday.

Comment: Do they also note that you should bring a sleeping bag and a tent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is "public transit" by your definition, but the private [Suburban Transit bus company](https://web.coachusa.com/suburban/), a division of Coach USA, operates a scheduled bus route between Monroe and the Port Authority Bus Terminal.  You can easily get from Brooklyn to the PABT by subway.

You can use their search form from "New York, NY" to "Monroe Township, NJ", or [here](https://web.coachusa.com/CoachUsaAssets/files/99/route300.pdf) is a PDF timetable for Route 300.  There are seven departures on Saturdays and four on Sundays.  The Rossmoor North Gate stop appears to be very close to Exit 8A.  Travel time from PABT is scheduled for just under one hour (subject to traffic, of course).

The regular [fare](https://web.coachusa.com/info/suburban/ss.toolkit.fares.asp) is $18.25 each way.

Comment: Thanks. This would be great if it weren't so expensive. It's about 7 minutes by car to the true destination. Have to weigh the price against the 18 minute drive of the next best option I found.

Comment: Actually found another closer bus stop on this route (0.9 miles away). Would be walking distance if not for the traveler's back problems. I'll accept this if the coming days don't reveal a cheaper close option. Thanks.

Comment: Bingo. Traveler is a senior citizen, eligible to pay half fare at all times. I'll accept. Thanks again.

Comment: @MattSamuel: Glad this helps.  The fare does seem high but is roughly in line with other options; for instance, NJT train from NY Penn to New Brunswick is $14.  Note that half fare apparently requires something called "blue coupons"; see [here](http://www.njtransit.com/sf/sf_servlet.srv?hdnPageAction=ReducedFareTo) near bottom of page.  If the traveler doesn't already have these, you can decide whether the effort to obtain them is worth the savings.

Comment: Even the full fare is cheaper than the tolls driving to and from Brooklyn.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will be useful to anyone else, but I found a bus stop in East Brunswick 12 minutes away on RT 18. Only saves $2.10 for a senior citizen, but for other travellers it saves $3. Probably will use that if the usual traveller brings company.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this unofficial New Jersey bus map](http://njbusmap.com), Middlesex County operates a local bus service, possibly called either MCAT or Community Shuttle.  The M1 and M6 routes appear to serve Monroe Township, and connect to rail service at New Brunswick and Princeton Junction respectively.

Their website doesn't seem to be working for me right now, so I can't confirm this or find the official schedules, but it may be worth investigating as another option.  Anyone who finds more details is welcome to edit them in.

Comment: I think this is the bus Google maps has you wait for from the address I'm searching from. It's walking distance from the house, but it seems to only run on weekdays, and there isn't even an afternoon bus on Friday.